# why my links not writing in my file

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, web-crawler, depth-first-search

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import readability
import time
import http.client

seed_url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sustainable_energy"
root_url = "https://en.wikipedia.org"
max_limit=5
#file = open("file_crawled.txt", "w")

def get_urls(seed_url):
r = requests.get(seed_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
links = soup.findAll('a', href=True)
valid_links=[]
 for links in links:
   if 'wiki' in links['href'] and '.' not in links['href'] and ':' not in links['href'] and '#' not in links['href']:
     valid_links.append(root_url + links['href'])
 return valid_links


visited=[]
def crawl_dfs(seed_url, max_depth):
depth=1
file1 = open("file_crawled.txt", "w+")
visited.append(root_url)
   if depth<=max_depth:
      children=get_urls(seed_url)
      for child in children:
           if child not in visited:          
                file1.write(child)                                    
                time.sleep(1)
                visited.append(child)
                crawl_dfs(child,max_depth-1)
   file1.close()

crawl_dfs(seed_url,max_limit)
```

dfs crawling use python 3.6
help me with the code, please correct where i am wrong, my crawled links are not writing to my file named file1. i dont know why i have tried everything at my end

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: Inside `crawl_dfs()` (which open file) you call `crawl_dfs()` which open again the same file (but you didn't close it yet) - it strange - maybe open it before you call `crawl_dfs()` first time.

Comment: Yes, you keep opening the file with the mode 'w+', so it's going to clear the .txt every time you enter the crawl_dfs()

Answer (score 2):

You have to open and close file only once - open before first `crawl_dfs()` and close after first `crawl_dfs()`

Tested:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
#import readability
import time
import http.client

# --- functions ---

def get_urls(seed_url):
    r = requests.get(seed_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
    links = soup.findAll('a', href=True)
    valid_links = []
    for links in links:
        if 'wiki' in links['href'] and '.' not in links['href'] and ':' not in links['href'] and '#' not in links['href']:
            valid_links.append(root_url + links['href'])
    return valid_links


def crawl_dfs(seed_url, max_depth, file_out):
    if max_depth >= 1:
       children = get_urls(seed_url)
       for child in children:
           if child not in visited:          
               file_out.write(child + "\n")                                    
               #time.sleep(1)
               visited.append(child)
               crawl_dfs(child, max_depth-1, file_out)

# --- main ---

seed_url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sustainable_energy"
root_url = "https://en.wikipedia.org"
max_limit = 1

visited=[root_url]

file1 = open("file_crawled.txt", "w+")

crawl_dfs(seed_url, max_limit, file1)

file1.close()
```